# How do I change the expiry date of an ElGamal subkey?

Tags: key-management, gnupg

I have a GPG key which has an ElGamal subkey (elg2048). Frankly, I don't remember why that is or whether I actually need it - I just have it. Now, I've just changed the expiry date of the key overall, using `gpg2 --edit-key`; however, the subkey expiration date seems not to have changed.

Questions:

- Can I change that subkey's expiration date?
- If so, how?
- If not - should I care? Should I just remove it?

Answer (score 5):

When you edit the key, you get a list of keys. Example::

```
sec  dsa2048/DEADBEAF
     created: 2014-10-10  expires: 2020-09-28  usage: SC  
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  elg2048/DEADBEAF
     created: 2014-10-10  expires: 2017-10-10  usage: E
```

If you enter `expire`, this will affect the "main" key, or perhaps the first key, not the subkey. For the subkey, type in `key 1`. You should now see `*` next to the `ssb`:

```
sec  dsa2048/DEADBEAF
     created: 2014-10-10  expires: 2020-09-28  usage: SC  
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb* elg2048/DEADBEAF
     created: 2014-10-10  expires: 2017-10-10  usage: E
```

now, an `expire` command will affect the subkey.